# Enable exec-maven-plugin while executing jar through java command

Tags: java, maven

I am using exec-maven-plugin to execute a shell script.

```
                   <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>exec-ui-install</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>

                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>bash</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>${basedir}/ui-build.sh</argument>
                                </arguments>
                                <skip>${exec.skip}</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>
```

I dont want this to run during build time (as i don't need to run it during build and  i am building it from windows). So i am using a parameter named  exec.skip and with its help i am able to skip it.

After building jar and moving it to Linux env i am using java command 
Ex:  java -cp : javaclass 
to run the jar. During this i need to execute "exec-maven-plugin" which was disabled during build mode. How do i pass "exec.skip=true" through java command so that i can run plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it.
The maven configuration of a project is used during the build of the project.
Once the artifact/component is constructed, you don't interact any longer with maven.

In your case, you should build your component with the suitable configuration parameters before moving it to linux.

Using a Maven profile with this specific configuration that is launched by a continuous integration tool could ease the task and make it reliable.